# Can I publish my branch from another user to my github pages

Tags: git, github, github-pages, git-bash

let's say my username is *mirrorr3ader* and I've published my GitHub-repository (...github.com/mirrorr3ader/my-blog) on GitHub Pages (...mirrorr3ader.github.io/my-blog/).

Is it possible to publish my branch from a GitHub-repository of another user (I have already agree the invitation) on my GitHub Pages? The other username is *otheruser* and the repository is his-blog (...github.com/otheruser/his-blog), my branch there is called r3ader.
Now I wish to published this branch on my GitHub Page too (like ...mirrorr3ader.github.io/his-blog/).

Hope you can understand what I mean and maybe can help. So if its possible, what I have to write in the Git Bash?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, you can't, you can only host from `github.com/<name>/<repo>` at `<name>.github.io/<repo>`.

Comment: ok thank you @jonrsharpe